# Sublime Linter/ ReferenceError: window is not defined?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2, jshint, sublimelinter

I know this is very basic question, but it's very strange that I cannot make it work, after spending hours, I really need help.

- OSX 10.8.4
- sublime Text 2  Version 2.0.2 Build 2221
- node v0.10.15
- jshint v2.1.7

Actually, I clean-installed sublime Text 2 just for this; just **Sublime Package Control** has been installed.

Firstly, I prepared a **foo.js** code:

```
function x(a, b)
{
    return a + b

res = x(10, 20)
console.log("res = " + res);
```

which result:

```
$ jshint foo.js                                       
foo.js: line 3, col 17, Missing semicolon.
foo.js: line 6, col 16, Missing semicolon.
foo.js: line 2, col 1, Unmatched '{'.

3 errors
```

So, **jshint** works as expected so far for the simple test.

I tried many things to get it work with Sublime Linter, but with no success, I clean-installed  the sublime app, then followed a tutorial video:

https://tutsplus.com/lesson/sublime-linter/

Looks easy, and Sublime Linter appearrently successfully installed and readme appears as the video show at 00:30, but in my case, after that, saving or whatever never triggers anything.

Well, I'm totally lost. Please advise. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I noticed sublimeText console shown a error!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./SublimeLinter.py", line 431, in _update_view
  File "./SublimeLinter.py", line 143, in run_once
  File "./sublimelinter/modules/base_linter.py", line 291, in run
  File "./sublimelinter/modules/javascript.py", line 72, in parse_errors
ValueError: Error from jshint: /Users/ken/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/SublimeLinter/sublimelinter/modules/libs/jshint/jshint.js:7881
})(window)
   ^
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.require.util (/Users/ken/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/SublimeLinter/sublimelinter/modules/libs/jshint/jshint.js:7881:4)
```

EDIT:
ok, this seems bug, I should have checked there first..

https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently a workaround for this:

The hotfix for this is - in Linux installations - to add

> `global.window = {};`

to the top of the file

> `~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/SublimeLinter/sublimelinter/modules/libs/jshint/jshint.js`

For Windows or OS/X installations you need to find the location of your Sublime Text package configurations.

Comment: Yes, I thought so - your own link finally brought me to that solution, but I wanted to provide it here for other stackoverflow users as well.

Answer (score 0):

For those that are still getting this error, edit the [JSHint configuration file](http://jshint.com/docs/) and add the following option:

```
"jshint_options": {
  "undef": true,
  "unused": true,
  "browser": true, /* Defines DOM globals such as window, navigator, FileReader, etc. */
  "jquery": true, /* OPTIONAL: globals exposed by jQuery */
  "devel": true,  /* OPTIONAL: globals such as debugging, alert  */
  "globals": {    /* OPTIONAL: set others that aren't predefined by JSHint */ 
    "Modernizr": true
  }
}
```

Learn more about the [pre-defined JSHint global variables](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#environments)